# Rails app not picking up styles in application.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, background-image, asset-pipeline, production-environment

My rails application is currently refusing to to pick up the body tag styles in my application.css on my production server (linode server) but it works on my localhost:3000. 
My asset pipeline looks like this

```
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require bootstrap_customization
 *= require datepicker
 *= require select2
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

I have tried switching the position of require_self and require_tree but it does not change anything. I will like to note ALL other styles are beign picked up, it is just the body tag that is not being picked up in application.css. Here is the code for the body tag

```
body{
background: transparent url('/assets/bg2.png');
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
}
```

I have tried adding classes to scope it more specifically in the css and i have made sure there is no permission on the image that wont allow it to be accessed. but it just shows a white background and uses the styles for the body tag above this one (the one that has the background image) but nothing else. this only happens in production, that background image shows perfectly on my localhost which is very weird does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If you're in production, are you sure you don't have to compile assets before? `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` etc.

Comment: I have done that several times already and I have set my production enviromnet to asset precompile = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cache of the server needed to be cleared. Also doing a `rake assets::clean` will remove all cached files both in development and production (Where ever you run it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 3, try using the asset-pipeline functions provided by rails, example:

```
body {
  background: transparent image_url('bg2.png');
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
}
```